# Pure JS: Multiple Forms Validation with some common Fields/elements and some unique fields/elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have multiple forms in a single page. Some of the elements/fields are common for all the forms and some of them are unique to every form. I need to validate all the forms and I want to validate using a single JS function. Everytime a form is submitted it would call validateForms() function before it is redirected to another page. Following are my JavaScript and Form layout. I can validate first form, however, I cannot validate other two. Following is the modified code. Please somebody help me.

**JavaScript**

```
    function validateForms(formName){
        var environment = document.forms[formName].environment;
        var browser = document.forms[formName].browser;
        var userType = document.forms[formName].userType;
        var username = document.forms[formName].usernameLoginUser;
        var password = document.forms[formName].passwordLoginUser;

        if (userType.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select userType");
            userType.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (environment.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select Environment");
            environment.focus();
            return false;
        }


        if (browser.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select Browser");
            browser.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (username.value == "")
        {
            window.alert("Please enter Username");
            username.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (password.value == "")
        {
            window.alert("Please enter password");
            username.focus();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

**HTML file:**

```
    <form name="firstForm" onsubmit="return validateForms('firstForm')" action="GET">
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <select name="userType">..</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <form name="secondForm" onsubmit="return validateForms('secondForm')" action="GET">
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <select name="browser">..</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <form name="thirdForm" onsubmit="return validateForms('thirdForm')" action="GET">
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works until you attempt to reference a variable that doesn't exist in the current form. You can step through it until that point, then an error is triggered. If you want to use the same function for each form, you'll need to test for the existence of the form variables before referencing them.

Glad you got it working. I changed the code a little bit to look like this:

```
var currentForm= document.forms[formName]

    if ( typeof(currentForm.environment) !== 'undefined'){
    if (currentForm.environment.selectedIndex < 1 ) {
                alert("Please Select Environment");
            currentForm.environment.focus();
            return false; 
    } 
} ;


    if ( typeof(currentForm.userType) !== 'undefined'){
    if (currentForm.userType.selectedIndex < 1 ) {
                alert("Please Select userType");
            currentForm.userType.focus();
            return false; 
    } 
} ;
```

I thought I'd still post it, just in case. I think as you get further along with this you'll want to test for the existence of the form variables before doing anything with them.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did make a blunder in my HTML (extra space in select name="environment "). finally figured out through chrome console debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below

```js
    function validateForms(form){
        var environment = document.forms[form].environment;
        var browser = document.forms[form].browser;
        var userType = document.forms[form].userType;
        var username = document.forms[form].usernameLoginUser;
        var password = document.forms[form].passwordLoginUser;

        if (userType.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select userType");
            userType.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (environment.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select Environment");
            environment.focus();
            return false;
        }


        if (browser.selectedIndex < 1)
        {
            alert("Please Select Browser");
            browser.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (username.value == "")
        {
            window.alert("Please enter Username");
            username.focus();
            return false;
        }
```

```html
   <form name="firstForm" onsubmit="return validateForms(this)" action="#" method="POST">
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <select name="userType">..</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <form name="secondForm" onsubmit="return validateForms(this)" action="#" method="POST">
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <select name="browser">..</select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <form name="thirdForm" onsubmit="return validateForms(this)" action="#" method="POST" >
    <select name="environment">..</select>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

I add attribute `method="post"` and changed `action="#"`. Also You can use `this` instead form name like`onsubmit="return validateForms(this)"`

Comment: thanks! it was mistake on my part. i will use 'this'.